# Гистограмма частотной характеристики столбца DataFrame

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, matplotlib

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Есть такой datafreame (df) созданный из сsv файла.
Нужно посчитать, сколько в данной таблице встречается `reg_name` и визуализировать на гистограмме или через barplot.

Нашла решение, как при помощи `def` посчитать, сколько раз каждая каждая область встречается:

```
def unique_vc(lst):
    uniques, count = np.unique(lst, return_counts=True)
    return (dict({u: c for u, c in zip(uniques, count)}))
unique_vc(df_2.reg_name)
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Получились такие выводные данные.

А как их визуализировать через `barplot`?

Comment: Добавьте, пожалуйста, в вопрос код создания датафрейма. Подозреваю, что это pandas

Comment: Добавлю плюс на вопрос, если замените картинки текстом. Спасибо.

Answer (score 2):

Попробуйте так:

```
df['reg_name'].value_counts().plot.bar(legend=True)
```